# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline || To sign in, use a web browser to open

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I created the aks cluster with azure service principal id and i provided the contributer role according to the subscription and resource group.

For each and every time when i executed the pipeline the sign-in is asking and after i authenticated it is getting the data.

Also the "kubectl get" task  is taking more than 30 min and is getting "Kubectl Server Version: Could not find kubectl server version"

*To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code CRA2XssWEXUUA to authenticate*

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What is the version of the created cluster?
I'm assuming from your snapshot that you are using `az` in order to get credentials for it.

Old azure auth plugin is deprecated in V1.22+. If you are using V1.22 or above you should use [kubelogin](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin) in order authenticate.

You will also need to update your kube config accordingly:

`kubelogin convert-kubeconfig`

and specifically if you're logging via az:

`kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli`

Note that the flag `-l azurecli` is important here: the default value is "devicecode" which will not consider your `az` as a logging method - and you will still be requested a browser authentication.

Alternatively, you can set environment variable:

`AAD_LOGIN_METHOD=azurecli`

Because you are getting sign in request and not the deprecation warning for the auth plugin, I suspect that you already have kubelogin installed on your agent, and you just need to update the kube config file

Answer (score 0):

What task are you using? There is official kubectl task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops

It requires the service connection.

If you still want to execute kubectl directly, you should run the following before the kubectl inside the AzureCLI task:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group "$(resourceGroup)" --name "$(k8sName)" --overwrite-existing
```

Comment: Yes i tried with your provided steps still i'm facing an issues

Comment: @Dinesh can you please update your question with full yml pipeline?

Comment: add --admin to the end of the get-credentials line

Answer (score 0):

Please use Selfhosted agents for executing your commands. looks like you have private endpoints for your AKS and requests are only allowed from trusted devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and for me the fix was to change the **Connection Type** in the stage definition from `Azure Resource Manager` to `Kubernetes Service Connection` - check on the screenshot below.

[image: Stage Connection Type]

Then you should be able to also specify the connection type in each of the tasks where you are running `kubectl` or `helm` commands. For example, in a `kubectl` task, under **Kubernetes Cluster** --> **Service connection type** use the `Kubernetes Service Connection`:

[image: Task connection type]

As mentioned by @DevOpsEngg, the problem could be related to private endpoints but I wouldn't say that it is regarding selfhosted agents, because I'm using these. As an extra comment - this started happening when I added more than one user to the cluster, so you might want to check user permissions and authentication. Unfortunately, I'm still getting used to K8s so I don't have more info about that.